# New roll of film rewound into canister after 4 exposures

Tags: film, point-and-shoot

I've been playing aroubd with an 1997 Canon Sure Shot Owl and I recently put a new roll of film in. The last roll I put in was fine, but after taking 4 or 5 photos the film rewound into the canister as if it was the last on the roll. After I loaded the film, I had a moment where the camera wasn't feeding the film but that was resolved when I pulled the tab slightly further out of the canister and was able to take a few pictures. I know how to fix an accidental rewind, but I'm not sire what to do about those first few exposures without over or double exposing?

Comment: When you say you "know how to fix an accidental rewind", you mean you know how to fish out the leader?  Is there any reason you can't set a fast shutter speed and fire through the first several frames in a dark room?

Answer (score 4):

If what happened is as you reported, i.e. only 4 frames exposed, you likely will be OK shooting the remainder. This is because the film cassette is light proof thus is protects the yet to be exposed film. Re-load, fire off 6 frames and then shoot.

One can never be quite positive about such things, something might not be as reported. If it were me, I would keep this rolls as sacrificial test roll. You can practice loading and rewinding etc. The decision to use this roll is based on how valuable the images you are about to take are to you.

Comment: I'll give you an up vote if you explain OP how to fire off the first 6 frames without actually exposing the already exposed frames a second time

Comment: Likely the first 6 frames are light fogged. Suppose the repair was accomplished in total darkness, then the 6 frames should be OK (not likely). In this case, reload the film as if it were an unused roll. With the lens cap on or suitable opaque cover over the lens, snap off 6 frames. The opaque cover will protect previously exposed frames. We often used this technique when we switched from one type of film to another. You can shoot B&W, maybe half a roll then rewind taking care to keep the tongue from rewinding. Remove this roll and replace with another. You can interchange at will.

Comment: To the digital shooter, it is almost counterintuitive that this won't overwrite the frame with black :)